# Разрешить открытие сайта только в iframe

Tags: javascript

Сабж: нужно не запретить открывать сайт в iframe, а сделать доступным **только** в iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
if (top === self) window.location="/not_allowed";
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что нужно :)